# Андроидовский шаринг

Tags: java, android, android-intent, uri

Как расшарить картинку с помощью **Intent**?

вот что я попытался сделать:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

// Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.good_one);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.drawable.good_one);

            sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Шаринг с sd карты:

```
Bitmap icon = mBitmap;
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
try {
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException e) {                       
        e.printStackTrace();
}
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Или так:

```
  final ImageView imgview= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

            Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imgview);
            if (bmpUri != null) {
                // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/*");
                // Launch sharing dialog for image
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
            } else {
                // ...sharing failed, handle error
            }
```

Посмотрите еще [здесь](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sharing-Content-with-Intents).

Comment: Здравствуйте, в вашем коде "mBitmap" - что такое ?

Comment: И хотелось бы все же шарить изображение из папки drawable

Comment: Шарьте из assets или с sd-карты из drawable вряд ли получится и это ,скажем, не тру.

Comment: Да, спасибо) Я сделал скрин, сохранив его на сд-карту, а дальше его уже расшарил.